# Using mathematical induction to prove recurrence system

Tags: math

Having fnc:

```
bool ISINTREE( int x, BinTree<int> t) 
  {
  bool  b = false

  if  (!t.isEmpty())
    {
    if  (x  ==  t.getRoot())
      { b = true }
    else
      {
      if (ISINTREE(x,t.leftTree()))
        { b = true }
      if (ISINTREE(x,t.rightTree()))
        { b = true }
      }
    }

  return  b 
  }
```

How to prove (using mathematical induction) that T(n)=   11 × 2^n − 7 is a   solution of 
the recurrence system for this fnc.

**EDITED**
Let F(n) = 11*2^n – 7
Now,
for k>0
T(k-1) = F(k-1) = 11*2^(k-1)-7
T(k) = 7+2*(T(k-1))
=7 + 2 * (11*2^(k-1) -7)
= 11*2^k -7

Answer (score 2):

What is `n` here?  The number of elements in the tree?  If so, surely we can say that, worst-case, this algorithm visits every single node in the tree, so the run-time is, worst-case, `T(n) = n`, in which case the premise (that this is `T(n) = 11 . 2^n - 7`) cannot be valid.

**UPDATE**

To satisfy the incredulity, let's take a look at the worst-case scenario (the item to find is not in the tree).  Without loss of generality, let's assume that we're looking at a perfectly balanced tree, i.e. each sub-tree has `(n-1)/2` elements.  Therefore under these assumptions, the recurrence relationship is:

```
T(n) = 2.T((n-1)/2) + 7
```

(I'd say that there really only 4 executable operations here, but let's call it 7 for simplicity).

Clearly, `T(n) = 11 . 2^n - 7` is not a solution for this relationship.

Comment: @Oli -1 for your answer is incorrect. And I suppose I won't here from you that you were wrong (in all those things), will I? No, surely I won't. But please, for the future reference, don't take part in any form in my questions.

Comment: @There: You gave your solution.  I pointed out a specific issue; we differ in our opinions on what the recurrence relationship is.  I explained why I think your recurrence relationship is wrong.  You have yet to offer an opinion on that specific issue.  If you want to have a grown-up debate, then I'm more than willing.  (If you only want to tell me that I don't know what I'm talking about, whilst avoiding specifics, then I'm not willing...)

Comment: @Oli my recurrence is correct, it is you who gave wrong answer. Unfortunately I'm preparing for quite important exam and I REALLY don't have time neither for a debate nor for explanation of why is it correct. After my exam (12.VI.11) I have no problem in showing you why it is the way it is.

Comment: @There: I'll take that as a "I don't know", then!  You certainly had plenty of time to argue up until now.  At least three people agree that my answer is valid...

Comment: @Oli if you would understand what I'm saying, then you should take it as **"I don't have time to explain it to you"** (and it is you who don't understand for I've provided prove as you've asked me to do so - just because you don't understand what is written there it doesn't mean that it is incorrect). It is you who is in error not me. And if you know anything about logic (formal logic) you would deduce that just because three people agree with you it doesn't really mean that you're right.

Comment: @There: You had plenty of time to construct that elaborate answer.  All I'm asking is that you explain why you think your recurrence relationship is correct (given that each sub-tree will have `(n-1)/2` elements, not `n-1`).  That should take 2 minutes.  If you're not prepared to do so, you should delete the question.